# Mortise latch gets stuck

Tags: doors

I had to replace my mortice latch as it cracked inside. It's happened to another door couple of years ago and replaced with no issues but this time on a different door the latch gets stuck when handle gets pulled down. I've pulled it off and tried again but same issue, even loosened the screws but nothing. Anyone got any info what would help?

Cheers.

[image]

Comment: Try loosening the screws that hold the handle, move the entire mechanism until operation is smooth, then retighten the screws,

Comment: You don't mention lubrication. That's usually step one for sticky hardware. Have you tried oiling it?